# Images in JQuery function are not displayed after deploying a rails app to Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using JQuery function to expand and contract ul list in a rails app. Everything work smoothly locally. However, after deploying to heroku the images can't be shown.

```
$(function()
{
 ...
    opener: {
       active: true,
       close: '/assets/Remove2.png',
       open: '/assets/Add2.png',

       openerCss: {
         ...
  });
```

Github Repo: https://github.com/ReemAlattas/AT2

Heroku App: http://at2.herokuapp.com/plans

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not able to find where in the code you have used those assets.. Could you specify?

Answer (score 0):

Give your Javascript file a .erb ending, then you can use the asset pipeline properly for this:

```
$(function()
{
 ...
    opener: {
       active: true,
       close: "<%= asset_path('Remove2.png') %>",
       open: "<%= asset_path('Add2.png') %>",

       openerCss: {
         ...
  });
```

Now when you deploy to Heroku your images will get the correct digest filename after precompilation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. That worked locally but still not on Heroku... I run rake assets:precompile but still :(

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout the heroku page and the github repo. The image is as @rlarcombe pointed out, but I saw another issue that you have called the raw script tag in your template:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-sortable-lists.js"></script>
```

That would be an issue when getting precompiled. You may try replacing all local script tags with `javascript_include_tag` and see if it works:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-sortable-lists" %>
```